# How to stop resubmission php

Tags: php, forms, redirect, post

I tried with  header('location:login.php'); but doesn't work it even don't wont to redirect page. Any ideas?
I've tried also with JavaScript to delete inputs but re-submission not stop.
No matter where put header('location:login.php'); it wouldn't work.

```
if(isset($_POST['vrsta_predmeta']) AND !empty($_POST['vrsta_predmeta']) AND 

    isset($_POST['res_text']) AND isset($_POST['glavni_dug']) AND isset($_POST['res']) AND isset($_POST['zaklj']) AND isset($_POST['povjerilac']) AND isset($_POST['duznik']) AND isset($_POST['predmet_zaveden'])){


    $racunob =  trim($_POST['rac']);
    $obrazlozenje = trim($_POST['obr']);     
    $ob_text = trim($_POST['res_ob']);  
    $res_text = trim($_POST['res_text']);
    $vrsta_pre = trim($_POST['vrsta_predmeta']);
    $izvrsenje = trim(strtolower($_POST['res']));
    $obrazac = trim($_POST['zaklj']);
    $povjerilac = $_POST['povjerilac'];
    $duznik = $_POST['duznik'];
    $datum= trim($_POST['predmet_zaveden']);
     foreach($povjerilac as $key){
     $lica = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO p_lica(povjerilac, doc_br, dokument_vlasnik) VALUES('$key', '$dok_broj', '$ses_val')");



    }       


    foreach($duznik as $key1){
     $lica1 = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO d_lica(duznik,doc_br, dokument_vlasnik) VALUES('$key1', '$dok_broj', '$ses_val')");


    }

    $insert_dok = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO document_tbl(dokument_vlasnik,dokument_broj,vrsta_dokumenta,zakljucak, resenje_izvrsenja,datum,resenje_text,obrazlozenje,obtext,racunob) VALUES('$ses_val','$dok_broj', '$vrsta_pre','$obrazac','$izvrsenje','$datum','$res_text','$obrazlozenje','$ob_text','$racunob')");
    if($lica -> execute() AND $insert_dok -> execute() AND $lica1 -> execute()){


       $lica -> close();
       $lica1 -> close();
       $insert_dok -> close();


      echo '<script>new Messi(\'Dokument uspjesno dodat.\', {title: \'Obavjestenje\', titleClass: \'success\', buttons: [{id: 0, label: \'Close\', val: \'X\'}]});</script>';
    header('location:login.php');
      }else{
       echo '<script>new Messi(\'Dokument uspjesno dodat.\', {title: \'Obavjestenje\', titleClass: \'anim warning\', buttons: [{id: 0, label: \'Close\', val: \'X\'}]});</script>'; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using prepared statements if you are not binding a single parameter? Half of your code is totally unnecessary. Are you in the process of learning PHP or is this supposed to be production code?

Comment: It should be production code. What part is unnecessary.?

Comment: I'll post an answer to address the code itself since it's supposed to be production. It's unsafe and SQL injection prone. Meanwhile, I suggest to accept John Conde's answer since it's a correct one.

Comment: It's not injectable. I shuld just add this on start: ob_start(); , thats corrct answer.

Comment: Ok, if you say it's not then I guess that's fine. Good luck (saves me tons of typing). Also, adding ob_start() is not the correct answer. Sadly, the code and the "solution" are horribly wrong and I suggest that you fix it the correct way. It would be wrong that that code goes to production.

Comment: I would like to see you toughts but I think it's not injectable...This is not login form it's place where users adding their documents.

Comment: Ok, why do you think it's not injectable? There is literally NOTHING in your code that prevents me to enter malicious SQL. Nothing. It doesn't matter if it's for your logged users or not, they can enter a single quotation mark and they'll get an error because your code doesn't escape a single thing, you're adding raw POST data into your db.

Comment: Because of this: http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-php-using-prepared-statements  But where will you add ' if you not logged?

Comment: You do understand that your code is not like the code on that link? You haven't specified any parameters nor have you **bound** any values that are supposed to be cleaned. You **passed** them directly to query. It even tells you the secure usage, shows the 3 lines of code but **you haven't done that**. I really have no other words to explain it better. What you've done is produced vulnerable code with PDO, just like the last example on that site.

Comment: Ok i don't see difference, could you show me how should I put queries?

Comment: I added that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590281/secure-code-with-mysqli     Please join the conversation.

Answer (score 3):

You can't redirect after outputting content. Since you output JavaScript you will need to change your redirect to be done by JavaScript.

```
echo '<script>new Messi(\'Dokument uspjesno dodat.\', {title: \'Obavjestenje\', titleClass: \'success\', buttons: [{id: 0, label: \'Close\', val: \'X\'}]});</script>';
header('location:login.php');
//^^^ This won't work.
// Try this instead. Redirects five seconds after the page is loaded.
echo 'window.setTimeout(function() {window.location = "login.php"}, 5000);';
```

As far as the form re-submission problem, you need to implement the [`POST/REDIRECT/GET` pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Basically, you need to do a redirect with a 303 HTTP header to prevent the browser from resubmitting the page. After the form is processed you would use something like this to do your redirect:

```
header('Location: /login.php', true, 303);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an encryption application for keeping my passwords on my server. I didn't want my session to be hijacked if I forgot to close the tab and have someone resubmit my session to gain access to all of my site passwords. What I came up with was to pass a timestamp from the login page to the main page. This time would be remembered if it were to be resubmitted. Then I had javascript compare times. If the time was not within 5 seconds I had it disable and clear all variables just incase the settings prevented redirection then redirect to the login page.